# Distance Key Node

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am trying to understand what is exactly the **Tolerance** of the **Distance Key** Node and so far there is no success.
From Blender manual Tolerance: "A threshold what the node considers a match between the key color and the foreground pixel. The tolerance affects how close a pixel needs to be to the background pixel to be considered an absolute match".
Can someone explain what does it mean? What are the **Foreground and Background pixels**?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual Entry for [Distance Key Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/matte/distance_key.html) is not terribly clear, but in terms of the two node inputs, the *Foreground* color is the *Key Color* node and the *Background* color is the color of the *Image* node at a particular position, that is the color of the pixel currently being examined in the image.

The *Tolerance* is a factor that's meant to allow for slight variations in the color of the image.  Consider the image color of a pixel as a point in a 3D space, where the three axis represent red, green and blue, if you're using the RGB setting.  Now consider the image color of the key color as another point.  The tolerance is a measure of how close the two colors have to be in that space for Blender to decide that they're a match.

This helps to allow for things like small variations in the lighting of a "green screen" that you're trying to remove from the image, for example.

Comment: Okay, suppose I have set Key Color (Foreground) = 0.5 (R,G,B = 0.5) and for Image input have plugged square gradient image form 0 to 1 along  X-axis. Then if I set the Tolerance value equal to 0.5 I should anticipate matching = true for values from 0.5 to 1 as well as from 0.5 to 0. But get something different (added the image above into the question)

Comment: Using your words setting the tolerance 0.5 it should cover the whole range (0 to 1) from the middle point where I have put Key color

Comment: The threshold distance isn't a simple subtraction.  It's the square root of the dot product of the distance squared.  See [COM_DistanceRGBMatte](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/compositor/operations/COM_DistanceRGBMatteOperation.cpp#L46) for a starting point.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Why does it utilize this formula, I mean a user doesn't think in category "square root of the dot product of the distance squared", how a user should understand how it works, or should simply switch slider back and forth until get something appropriate?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a good intuition for this.  The best I have is the obvious "bigger values means more shades get included; but sensitivity falls off rapidly, like light does over distance."  I suspect that the whole point is the last bit, that sensitivity should fall off the same way that light intensity falls off.

Comment: Hm, yea it makes sense why it's not linear, thanks for sharing